# Active Record has_many through more than one model

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

Is it possible to access objects more than one model away?

For example let's say I have

```
class Contact <ActiveRecord:Base
 has_many :interactions
end

class Interaction <ActiveRecord:Base
 belongs_to :contact
 belongs_to :course_presentation 
end

class CoursePresentation <ActiveRecord:Base 
 has_many: interactions
 belongs_to :course
end

class Course <ActiveRecord:Base
 has_many :course_presentations
end
```

Right now I know I could write a through relationship via contacts to course presentations and then get all the course related to all the course presentations or I could do

```
contact.interactions.map{ |i| i.course_presentation.course }
```

I would like to be able to pull courses related to a contact directly so ... e.g.

```
contact.courses
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I believe so. Just add the following:

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :interactions
  has_many :course_presentations, through: :interactions
  has_many :courses, through: :course_presentations
end
```

Comment: That works. Thanks. Is there any best practice regarding this? I am a little worried that it might hide meaning to other developers when they see contact.courses

Comment: Well, if you have any ERDs, or as I prefer, tests, just make sure they're included in the model, with every has_many through step documented and tested. If you like you can add a note telling them to watch out for this semi-brittle relationship

Comment: Use https://github.com/fazibear/colorize if you want to colorize the tests nicely to add warnings and such